# Azure edgeAgent not starting after upgrade to 1.3.0

Tags: azure-iot-edge

After upgrading our edge devices to the latest iot-edge version (1.3.0), the edgeAgent container refuses to start. This in turn completely bricks the devices. Only option is to prune the agent container + images so it reverts to an older version again.

Anyone experienced something similar or has a suggestion on how fix this?

**Old situation:**

Ubuntu 18.04 server on Amd64 hardware
IotEdge runtime version: 1.2.7
azureiotedge-hub:1.2.8
azureiotedge-agent:1.2.8

*Running our modules without a problem.*

**New situation:**

IotEdge runtime version: 1.3.0
azureiotedge-agent:1.3.0
azureiotedge:hub:1.2.8 (edgeAgent crashes before it upgrades to 1.3.0)

**What happens:**

After upgrading the iotEdge runtime to 1.3.0 everything works fine. Problems start after releasing the new iotedge-agent software. After deploying the new manifest to the devices the azureiotedge-agent:1.3.0 is being downloaded and started. It crashes because the service can't access the storage folder (/iotedge/storage/edgeAgent) which binds to the host machine.

I can follow the steps in the updated ['agentStart.sh' script](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/1.3.0/edge-agent/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Service/agentStart.sh):

- I see a user 'edgeagentuser' with UID 13622 on the host has been created.
- The ownership on the storage directory and management socket are being changed to '13622'.
- The Edge Agent Service dll is being started and crashes.

**The logs**

`iotedge check` shows only a DNS server warning. Everything 'green' besides that.

iotEdgeAgent container logs

```
2022-07-19 08:23:29  Starting Edge Agent
2022-07-19 08:23:29  Changing ownership of storage folder: /iotedge/storage//edgeAgent to 13622
2022-07-19 08:23:29  Changing ownership of management socket: /var/run/iotedge/mgmt.sock
2022-07-19 08:23:29  Completed necessary setup. Starting Edge Agent.
2022-07-19 08:23:29.368 +00:00 Edge Agent Main()
<6> 2022-07-19 08:23:29.935 +00:00 [INF] - Initializing Edge Agent.
<6> 2022-07-19 08:23:30.473 +00:00 [INF] - Version - 1.3.0.57041647 (b022069058d21deb30c7760c4e384b637694f464)
<6> 2022-07-19 08:23:30.475 +00:00 [INF] -
﻿
[excluded the ASCII art]

﻿﻿<0> 2022-07-19 08:23:30.527 +00:00 [FTL] - Fatal error reading the Agent's configuration.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/iotedge/storage/edgeAgent' is denied.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Service.Program.GetOrCreateDirectoryPath(String baseDirectoryPath, String directoryName) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/edge-agent/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Service/Program.cs:line 361
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Service.Program.MainAsync(IConfiguration configuration)
```

Comment: You should [open an issue on the project's repo](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues) to report this

Answer (score 0):

We are currently discussing this issue with other people on this thread:
https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/6541